# Bokeh export all charts, tables in a single image

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I m building some chart usign bokeh chart.

This is the output:

[image]

Now I want to know if is possible to create a Print or an image to print. In my case I can export as image only chart and not Table too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's nothing built into Bokeh for that.
However, you can implement it directly using some of the links in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18581496/564509

Alternatively, you can just print the whole web page using [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print).